# node.js fs.rename() error enoent

Tags: node.js, express, rename, fs

after uploaded a file to my server i try to move it to another folder(same disk), and i got thie error

```
{[Error:ENOENT,rename 'F\myproject\1b231234nsdifhoi2323']
  errno:34,
  code:ENOENT,
  path:'F\\myproject\\1b231234nsdifhoi2323'
}
```

am on windows and use

```
app.use(express.bodyParser({
    uploadDir:'./Temp'
}));
```

here is my rename code

```
exports.upload = function(req, res,next){
    console.log( req.body);
    console.log(req.files);
    var tmp_path = req.files.product_video.path;
    var target_path = '\\Video\\' + req.files.product_video.name;

    console.log(tmp_path);       // Temp\1b231234nsdifhoi2323
    console.log(target_path);    // \Video\name

    fs.rename(tmp_path, target_path, function(err) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err)
        };
        fs.unlink(tmp_path, function() {
            if (err){
                console.log(err)
            }else{
                res.send('File uploaded to: ' + target_path + ' - ' + req.files.product_video.size + ' bytes');

            }
        });
    });
};
```

it looks like i get the path wrong,but i cannot figure it out !

Comment: Are you on Windows? If so you should include the colon (`:`) in the drive part of the path name i.e. `F:`.

Comment: but the Temp and Video folder is in same disk

Comment: well i edit the var target_path = 'F:\\myproject\\Video\\' + req.files.product_video.name; it works thanx

Comment: For future reference, you can look up the E*** error codes here: https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/master/deps/uv/include/uv.h

Comment: @paynestrike, it will be better to use var target_path = __dirname + "\\Video" + req.files.product_video.name  (if your file is in F:\myproject)

Answer (score 2):

You are accessing an **unexisting file** - because a path does not.

**Try edit path:**
change `"F\myproject\1b2"` to `"F:/myproject/1b2"` or `"F:\myproject\1b2"`

**If doesn't work, use:** (__dirname will make a path relative to the script)
`__dirname + "/../../myproject\1b2"`

**For debugging:**
Try `read` this file (if you get same error - it means that path is bad and `rename` is fine)

Comment: bed? is that a typo for bad?

Comment: :D fixed .. yes, it was a typo

Answer (score 0):

To avoid slash issue, you can use `path.sep` so it will handle the slash `\` based on the OS.